# Dart: How to close browser window?

Tags: dart

How can I close a browser page via eg. an HTML button and Dart?
I've tried

```dart
window.close();
```

which doesn't appear to do anything;

I've also tried :

```dart
window.document.$dom_dispatchEvent();
```

using CloseEvent, but I'm not sure how to set that up.

I've also tried HTML and javascript without success.

Please advise how this can be done. It's needed for desktop-type apps IMO.

Comment: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Window.html:

window.close: 
"This method should only succeed if the WindowBase object is script-closeable and the window calling close is allowed to navigate the window.

A window is script-closeable if it is either a window that was opened by another window, or if it is a window with only one document in its history.

A window might not be allowed to navigate, and therefore close, another window due to browser security features."

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```dart
<form method="post">
<input type="button" value="Close Window" 
onclick="window.close()">
</form>
```

Maybe try

```dart
window.focus(); window.close()
```

Comment: No luck with those. I believe that the first one (html) worked once but no longer does. In Dart, there doesn't appear to be window.focus(), and window.close() doesn't appear to do anything.